# How to build a powerful crawler like google's?

Tags: performance, scrapy, web-crawler, distributed-system

I want to build a crawler which can update hundreds of thousands of links in several minutes. 
Is there any mature ways to do the scheduling? 
Is distributed system needed? 
What is the greatest barrier that limits the performance? 
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python you could go with Frontera by Scrapinghub

https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera

https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera/blob/distributed/docs/source/topics/distributed-architecture.rst

They're the same guys that make Scrapy.

There's also Apache Nutch which is a much older project.
http://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: MetalloyD,can you tell me what is the difference between scrapy-cluster, distributed-frontera? I am puzzled.what is each's pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a distributed crawler but don't reinvent the wheel, use Apache Nutch. it was built exactly for that purpose, is mature and stable and used by a wide community to deal with large scale crawls.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of processing and memory required would need distributed processing unless you are willing to compromise speed. Remember you'd be dealing with billions of links and terabytes of text and images